# Communication among the tiers in three tier architecture

Tags: .net, architecture

I have a very basic question. In three tier architecture, each tiers are deployed on a separate physical computer. For example, presentation.dll is deployed on machine A, business.dll is deployed on machine B, and dataAccess.dll is deployed on machine C. My question is

1. how these three tiers communicate with each other?
2. Can we add a reference of one dll into another as we normally do in Visual Studio IDE?

Please help.

Comment: You cannot simply add a reference.  How .NET communicate within a process is different then how it communicates across processes.  If it is on another computer then for sure it is another process.

Answer (score 1):

You have options. The biggest and arguably most powerful communication system will be Windows Communication Foundation, which can be configured to do many types of communication.

A simpler solution would be WebAPI setup. It's less flexible, but also less complex.

Answer (score 1):

Well those are 2 not so basic questions indeed:

1. The .net standard way is to use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). IMHO I would recommend using [NetTCPBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752250%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since this is all going to happen inside the same intranet right? Here you'll have to solve many concerns such as security (are you going to authenticate at each tier?, which authentication mechanism are you going to use?).
2. When you use WCF you will add a reference to a service which you can use and see in your code as any external DLL, however you will be using proxies of the real classes that will be deployed in the next tier.